# PHP Mongodb find() not working as expected

Tags: php, mongodb, find

I got a very basic Mongodb Find request which seems not to work. php 7+
I want something like in SQL: `where 'common' LIKE %Burk%`
[image]

The simple query is to call the `countries collection` and produce *Burkina Faso* as output

QUERY 1:

```
$countries_tb= $db->selectCollection('country_city_data');
 $countries = $countries_tb->find([],[
    'common' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('Burk')]);
var_dump($countries);
```

the `var_dump` prints everything in the database

QUERY 2:

when I do find(without the empty []), it var_dumps nothing necessary

```
 $countries = $countries_tb->find(/*without the []*/ [
    'common' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('Burk')]);

var_dump($countries);
```

I get this:

[image]

I have also tried this format.

QUERY 3:

```
 $countries = $countries_tb->find(
                     array('name'=>
 array(  'common'=>new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('Burk'))));

                var_dump($countries);
```

Still no success.

> **As suggested by `@noobProgrammer` below, doing like this:**

```
 $countries_tb->find(['name' => 
                  ['common'=>new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('Burk')]], 
                  ['typeMap' => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']]);
```

Produces this;

[image]

instead of the word ***'Burkina Faso'***

Still NO Success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working finally!

This is what I did.

```
$countries = $countries_tb->find(array('name.common' =>   array('$regex' =>  'Burk') ) );
```

Notice the `.` in `name.common`

Here is my `foreach` loop'

```
foreach( $countries as $country => $name) { 

   foreach ($name as $n){

       if(isset($n->common)){

            var_dump($n->common);

        }

   }
}

//It prints out:    country_cities.php:90:string 'Burkina Faso' (length=12)
```

---

Somehow, this does NOT work

```
$countries = $countries_tb->find(
                         array('name'=>
                                 array('common' =>   
                                         array('$regex' =>   'Burk')) ) );
```

### This is the JSON'

```
{"_id":"55a0f42f20a4d760b5fc306d","altSpellings":["BF"],"area":272967,"borders":["BEN","CIV","GHA","MLI","NER","TGO"],"callingCode":["226"],"capital":"Ouagadougou","cca2":"BF","cca3":"BFA","ccn3":"854","cioc":"BUR","currency":["XOF"],"demonym":"Burkinabe","landlocked":true,"languages":{"fra":"French"},"latlng":[13,-2],"name":{"common":"Burkina Faso","native":{"fra":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"}},"official":"Burkina Faso"},"region":"Africa","subregion":"Western Africa","tld":[".bf"],"translations":{"cym":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"deu":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"fin":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"fra":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"hrv":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"ita":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"jpn":{"common":"ブルキナファソ","official":"ブルキナファソ"},"nld":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"por":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"},"rus":{"common":"Буркина-Фасо","official":"Буркина -Фасо"},"spa":{"common":"Burkina Faso","official":"Burkina Faso"}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

All filters should be in the first array parameter

`$countries_tb->find(['area' => 272967, 'capital' => 'Ouagadougou'] , 
                     options );`

The second param is for options. You should pass typeMap as an option to convert the object to an array

`$options = ['typeMap' => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']]`;

Comment: Thats very interesting, because I want something like in SQL: `where 'common' LIKE %Burk%` , it seems like the `mongodb` approach is very complicated for such a simple `query`

Comment: Still same results man, please check my edit above.... Really exausted all my resources and still Nothing works

Comment: @ErickBest, What actually looking the output . Could you please explain bit specific about the result.

Comment: I want it to output the word `'Burkina Faso'`.... am imagining it to be something like we would do in `SQL`  `where 'common' LIKE %Burk%` I have a foreach loop
but it produces no expected result